# Debug (get to know) what has controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, controller, each

I know from a tutorial, that `<%= controller.controller_name %>` prints out the controllers name.

Now i figure out, how to dumnp all the hidden information in the `controller`.

i tried with

```
<%= debug(controller.instance_methods.to_yaml) if Rails.env.development?  %>
<%= debug(controller.to_yaml) if Rails.env.development?  %>
```

or with an each, but nothing works. Please teach me (without using a gem) how to see all the nice informations.

Comment: Try `methods` instead of `instance_methods`

Comment: Thx, that helped me. can you maybe explain me the differences of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Object#methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-methods) to get all the methods in an object

```
controller.methods
```

[Module#intance_methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) is a class method, So you should call it using Class.

```
controller.class.instance_methods
```

You can pass `false` to not include inherited methods

```
controller.class.instance_methods(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I not really understand your question, is this what you want?

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```